# How to design multiple tags feature with Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, ios6

I have my first iOS app with Core Data, and there is an Entry entity. Entry has the attribute called "Tag" and it's NSString.

So now when user created a new Entry he can put any string into Tag field and it will be stored in Core Data as NSString, which can be used later for search by tag.

The thing is I want to implement multiple tags feature in my app and I can't figure out how to do it, what's the correct design for cases like this in iOS, considering using Core Data.

For example, if someone wants to create an Entry and give it tags like "food", "groceries", "apples". How should I assign all of them to my property of Entry entity? How should I store them in Core Data? As a separate entity Tags with unique ids? How should I retrieve them and how can user edit multiple tags for an Entry?

Thank you in advance for answers.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 common ways to do that.

1. the simplest one is to store comma separated tags in your NString. (but you won't be able do filtering and other operations involving tags)
2. Create another entity - Tag with name and id. And have many-to-many relationship (assuming one tag can be used by several entries)
   a good explanation on how to do that is given here [cdrelationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html)

Comment: Thank you, I'll read Apple Docs one more time. The 1st one doesn't suit me because I need multiple tags not in one string, I will have them on server too. So approach 2 would be my choice. Though can you suggest how can I implement 2 approach with my original entity? NSString wouldn't work here, I'd need separate string for every tag.

Comment: @Tala Why specifically give the tag an ID attribute as well? I'm pretty that it's best practice, but I can't come up with a good reason why, since individual tags are pretty much guaranteed to be unique anyway.

Comment: 1. suppose you have entities which store multiple tag ids. Storing `int` or `long` takes much more less memory then `String`, also since you usually need to build indexes for db queries, memory consumption difference is huge
2. actually, tags grow really fast and there can be name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in multiple way. You could just separate your tags with the character of you choice and just split the NSString in you code to retrieve your tags. 
Or, if you want to make things right, just use another entity to store your tag's IDs.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I wanted to make separate entity. But how can I implement a reference to this entity from my Entry entity? NSString wouldn't work, I need a way to add and **edit** multiple tags for every Entry.

Answer (score -2):

[Use that tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)

This will help you to understand core data.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. ..."*

Comment: Thanks, but I already have read this. I understand how to make a new entity and make relationship in CD, I don't get though how to implement this with my original entity's property Tag, which is NSString. I'd need more than that, can't figure out just yet how to make multiple tags for an Entry in iOS.